# I know it's true, but why?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A ∪ (B' ∩ C' ∩ A) = A$$

Does anyone know of a law that stipulates this?  I can't find anything in my textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question, but $B'\cap C' \cap A \subset A$ and for any subset $X$ of $A$ ($X \subset A$) it holds that $X\cup A=A$.